# Multiline declaration in Python Django templates

Tags: python, django, syntax, django-templates

Is it possible to use them? Something like

```
{% for long_variable_name in list %}
  {% declare %}
    bool_var = long_variable_name.sublist1.count > 0 and\
      long_variable_name.sublist2.count > 0
    ...
```

Similar question is about the {% if %}'s statements. Although as I understand, anyway it's better not to write complex boolean statements in them since if is very limited with operations and parentheses.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to format a complicated data structure in several forms, depending on its contents. So now I'm forming a logical condition and an if operator which will choose which form to use

Comment: Doing such things in template is not natural to me. I'd try to do it in view, or even write a custom template tag or filter to do the work, but not use the template itself.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same hope as you.
According to [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808878/multi-line-string-in-django-include-statement) there is no way to use multiline declarations in Django templates.