# Multi line string in Django 'include' statement

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to be DRY with my Django templates, and have some code that I mix with CSS for a simple hover-over popup. I'd like to reuse the code, but the contents of my popup will be HTML that may well span over multiple lines. Is it possible to stuff multi-line strings into a template variable?

I tried doing something funky with blocks and `block.super` but that only seems to work when extending (not `include`)

Here's an example of what I'd like to do. Is it possible?

`index.html`

```
 <body>
 <h2>My Popup</h2>
 {% include "snippets/popup.html" with class="p" spantext="Hover me" popupdiv="""
  <h2>This is a popup!</h2>
     <ul>
          <li>Something</li>
          <li>Something else</li>
     </ul>
 """
%}
 </body>
```

`snippets/popup.html`

```
 <div class="{{ class }}">
     <span class='pointer'>{{ spantext }}</span>
     <div class="popup">
         {{ popupdiv }}
     </div>
 </div>
```

I know it's not possible to have multi-line template tags in Django, but is there any way round this, other than squashing all my div html onto one line, and escaping any quotes?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out "Parsing until another template tag" is what I was after. http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html

Here's my code:

`tags.py` (in the `templatetags` folder)

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template.base import Node, TemplateSyntaxError

register = template.Library()

class PopupNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist, class_name, spantext):
        self.nodelist = nodelist
        self.class_name = class_name
        self.spantext = spantext

    def render(self, context):
        popup_html = get_template("ordersystem/snippets/popup.html")
        context.update({
            'class' : self.class_name,
            'spantext' : self.spantext,
            'popupdiv' : self.nodelist.render(context)
        })
        return popup_html.render(context)

@register.tag('popup')
def show_popup(parser, token):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endpopup',))
    tokens = token.split_contents()
    if len(tokens) != 4:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("show_popup is in the format 'popup with class=X spantext=Y")
    try:
        context_extras = [t.split("=")[1].strip('"') for t in tokens[2:]]
    except IndexError:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("show_popup is in the format 'popup with class=X spantext=Y")
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return PopupNode(nodelist, *context_extras)
```

Then within my html file I can just do:

```
{% popup with class_name=management spantext=Manage %}
<h2>This is a popup!</h2>
     <ul>
          <li>Something</li>
          <li>Something else</li>
     </ul>
{% endpoup %}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way should be to create a templatetags in your module with an **inclusion tag**.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

So imagine your are YourModule yourModule with a folder templatetags and the file **popup_tag.py**

```
yourModule/
---- views.py
---- models.py
---- templates/
     ---- snippet/
          ---- popup.html
---- templatetags/
     ---- __init__.py
     ---- popup_tag.py
```

Your **popup_tag.py** could look like the following lines :

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def show_pop_up(class, span_text, popupdiv):
    return {'class': class,
            'span_text': span_text,
            'pop_up_div': pop_up_div}

register.inclusion_tag('snippet/popup.html')(show_popup)
```

Then, you just have to call your tag in your template **index.html**.

```
{% load popup_tag %}

{% show_popup "class" "span_text" "popupdiv" %}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but my guess is that since you're still using a template tag (`show_popup`) you still can't add text that spans multiple lines? I've revised my question to be a bit more explicit about what I want

Comment: Do you want absolutly use an html list ? Whether you can use a loop variable when you call your template tag. Like {% show_popup "class", "span_text" variable %} and in your template {% for item in variable %}<li>item</li>{% endfor %}

Comment: No, a HTML list was just an example. I'll be using almost anything in my popups